# Effect of allowing condition of n=0 on a set X on which relation R is based?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let X={ (m,n) ∈ Z×Z, n \neq 0 }
Let R be the relation on X defined by ((m,n),(m’,n’)) ∈ R iff mn’=m’n.
(a) Prove that R is an equivalence relation on X.
(b) What happens if we allow n=0 in X?

---

I got  the  first question fine  but  I'm not  able  to  understand the  repercussions  if  n=0 were  to  be  allowed.  I mean m can  have  values  of  0 anyways so  how  would  is  possibly  affect  the  resonating?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA n≠0 is what I meant sorry

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you allow $n=0$. Then $((1,0), (0,0)) \in R$ and $((0,0), (0,1) \in R$. By transitivity, $((1,0), (0,1)) \in R$ implying $1 \cdot 1 = 0 \cdot 0$, a contradiction. This means that we lose transitivity by allowing $n=0$ and thus $R$ is no longer an equivalence relation.